# Why use Customer/Buyer API credentials?

Tags: api, testing, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm integrating PayPal into a client's website for the first time.
I've been using seller and buyer test accounts and testing on Sandbox.
I've used the seller's API credentials in creating Buy Now buttons dynamically, and these credentials are used in the NVP that goes through cURL.
I'm also using the credentials in the IPN listener that does the business logic once a buyer makes a payment.

I've tested being a buyer who buys using a PayPal account and I've also tested buying the product using credit cards.

1. I'm just wondering, why do we need the buyer's API credentials? Are there are some important tests I'm missing out where these credentials are used to make API calls?
2. How can I create errors in order to take advantage of "Negative" testing, which is an option that shows up if I click on the "Profile" of one of the test sandbox accounts in the new developer interface?

I know some of these questions can be answered by looking at paypal's developer site, and I've been through its site pages over and over again, I'm asking here on SO because while PayPal is comprehensive, I don't find it clear enough for a beginner like me.

Comment: May i know which NVP API operation requires buyer's API credentials ??

Comment: I don't know myself, that's why I'm asking why PayPal gives these credentials, what is the use of them? perhaps there are some useful tests that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Each and every PayPal account has API credentials,whether it is live or sandbox. Buyers can also perform NVP API calls & Buyers can also be seller.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions.

1. These credentials are what allow you to access the account via API call.  It's an authentication method similar to using a user id and password for accessing the account, performing actions on the account and retrieving information from the account.  You would not want just anyone to be able to access your account, so API credentials are used for accessing your account.
2. If you are wanting to use negative testing, refer to the developers guide.  This will tell you want you need to pass to trigger specific error codes.  Passing different values for such things as amount, cvv2, the address and etc will trigger different errors.  As for triggering errors on the profile, you wouldn't be able to do this with negative testing, if this is what you are asking.

Comment: I understand about API credentials. I have successfully used API credentials for testing transactions, but I've only used the *seller* test account. My question is particularly when do we need to use the *buyer* API credentials?

Comment: You wouldn't use the buyer API credentials for anything.  Normally a buyer would not provide you with their API credentials for anything.

Comment: Alright thanks. And for question 2- about negative testing. I'm using the ButtonManagerAPI to make buttons dynamically and I'm then using an IPN listener. Part of my NVP request is something like this: `BUTTONCODE=HOSTED&BUTTONTYPE=BUYNOW&L_BUTTONVAR1=amount=".$total`. I just want to make sure - for negative testing, is it this `amount` that should include error numbers to be processed as an error? And can I do negative testing at all with the ButtonManagerAPI for Buy Now buttons? (Not using express checkout or anything fancy).

Comment: Negative testing would be used for API calls for processing payments such as DoDirectPayment or EC payments, you wouldn't be able to use negative testing for the ButtonManager API's.

Comment: I see. I only mentioned the ButtonManagerAPI but am not sure whether or not my account has DoDirectPayment. I've made another question, could you please visit and answer it? It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653240/does-this-simple-paypal-solution-allow-credit-card-transactions-and-negative-tes

Comment: I woudl need the email address of the test sandbox seller account, to look it u to verify if it has Website Payments Pro enabled on it.